# How do I remove an apostrophe from the filename?

Tags: syntax, coldfusion, filenames

I need to remove the spaces and any apostrophes from the filename of my file that is uploaded. I have figured out how to remove the spaces but I am not sure how to remove the apostrophes. I am using coldfusion. Below is my code for removing the spaces. How should I modify this code to also remove any apostrophes. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
  <cfset mySpaceFreeVariable = ReReplace(filename, "[[:space:]]","","ALL")>
```

Comment: Rather than trying to identify all the unwanted characters, why not get rid of anything that is not a wanted character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<cfset mySpaceFreeVariable = ReReplace(filename, "[\s']","","ALL")>
```